# Inject modules conditionally in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Angular app structure is like this:

**App.js**

```
angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
    'RateRequestApp.services',
    'RateRequestApp.controllers',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar',
    'textAngular',
    'angularFileUpload'
]);
```

I am using different HTML files for different pages and I am not using 
Angular's `$route`, but still I want to use same app in all pages with different controllers.

As you can see I am injecting third party modules to my app. The problem is that in some pages I don't want some of this modules, How can I avoid them where I don't need them?

Comment: Create different modules for different pages/views and inject only those necessary for that perticular page/view.

Comment: @simpe My question is that, Can I do it in this same app.js file. like checking which page or which controller is active and inject only needed modules

Comment: [Here](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/conditional-dependency-injection-with-angularjs.html) you can read about conditional dependency injection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can do it something like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('RateRequestApp', [
    'RateRequestApp.services',
    'RateRequestApp.controllers',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'angular-loading-bar'
]);

var lazyModules = ['textAngular', 'angularFileUpload'];

angular.forEach(lazyModules, function(dependency) {
    myApp.requires.push(dependency);
});
```

In this case you may inject the modules conditionally. (But please note, lazy loading of some module may not work where there is some configuration needed.)

Comment: "lazy loading of some module may not work where there is some configuration needed."  What is solution?

Comment: @Shashank Agrawal Just for notification adding coment - "lazy loading of some module may not work where there is some configuration needed." What is solution?

Comment: Hi @StackOverFlow Are you facing any specific error? It's been long time I stopped using AngularJS so I can try to resolve any specific issue.

Comment: @Shashank Agrawal - I want to add module conditionally. I tried to push module in  myApp.requires but didn't worked with angularjs 1.x. . Tried in .run() , .config - no luck