# How to inject a module dynamically inside another module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular app is like below
App.js

```
 angular.module('myapp', [
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngMessages',
    authModule,
    loginModule
]);

//prodductModule
```

In my login module I have a ajax call using $http. After receiving proper response from server I want to initialize another module suppose "productModule".

How to do it? Is it possible in angular?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inject modules conditionally in angularjs app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687059/inject-modules-conditionally-in-angularjs-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', [
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngMessages'
]);
```

Now, later in your AJAX call code, you can write like this:

```
myApp.requires.push('productModule');
```

Take a look at [Inject modules conditionally in AngularJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687059/inject-modules-conditionally-in-angularjs-app/27687339#27687339)

Comment: This will not work in runtime. You can do this only before app is being proceeded.

Comment: Oh! But we've been using this for a long time along with the oclazyload you have mentioned.

Comment: With oczlazload it will work, you didn't mentioned this library before.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - NO, it is not supported by default.

Long answer - SLIGHTLY - using 3rd party libraries like: https://oclazyload.readme.io/

But my opinion is that you shouldn't do that, Angular is designed for apps, so just let whole app load before start. Even big app will start fast. Loading modules dynamically can cause unwanted lagging and modules are not unloaded when not needed.

But final decision is yours as ussual :)

**EDIT:** 
If you are trying to load other modules when user is logged in. We ussually do it like redirect to production app with authentication token in querystring, so server let us download javascript with app. But this is not necessary everytime, ussually we load whole app.

Answer (score 0):

You can't load **Module** dynamically. Angular needs to know all module names during its bootstrap process.

To solve this problem you can create empty module and pass its name to your app.
then load module JS file via **RequireJS** and register each services or controller one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Load module dynamically, I would suggest to go with require js.